# Finding Max value and Average Of All elemements in 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

**EDIT II**

I'm finally getting somewhere, now i get my random values with a return from the maxavg() function.

My only question now is, when i run the program i always get:

average: 0
maximum: 33

why? it does not make much sense.

Here is the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <limits.h>

int GetRand(int min, int max);
struct maxavg;

int main ()
{
int a[21][21], i , j, average, maximum, ret;


for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 21; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = GetRand(0, 100);

        printf("%3d" , a[i][j]);
    }

        a[2][15] = -1;
        a[10][6] = -1;
        a[13][5] = -1;
        a[15][17] = -1;
        a[17][17] = -1;
        a[19][6] = -1;

    printf("\n");

}




printf("average = %d \n maximum = %d", average, maximum);




return 0;

}



// random seed
int GetRand(int min, int max);
int get () 
{
int i, r;
for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
 {
    r = GetRand(0, 100);
    printf("Your number is %d \n", r);
}
 return(0);
 }

int GetRand(int min, int max)
{
static int Init = 0;
int rc;             

if (Init == 0)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Init = 1;
}

rc = (rand() % (max - min +1) +min);

return (rc);
}


struct pair
{
int max;
int avg;
};





// max and average

struct pair maxavg()
{
struct pair p;
int max=INT_MIN, sum=0, count=0, avg, i, j, current;

for(i = 0; i < 21; i++){
    for(j =0; j < 21; j++){
        if(current > -1){
            sum = sum + current;
            count = count + 1
            ;if(current > max){
                max = current;
            }
        }

    }
}
avg = sum/count;
printf("Max is %d \n", max);
printf("Average is %d \n", avg);
p.max = max;
p.avg = avg;

return p;
```

}

EDIT:

So here is what i'm doing, i get error messages:

Average:

```
// Average Code

value = a[i][j];
int actualvalue, suma = 0, quant;


for(i=0; i<21; i++){
for(j=0; j<21; j++){
    if (actualvalue > -1){
        a[i][j] = actualvalue;
        suma = suma + actualvalue;
        // sum actual value + nextvalue (sum of all > -1) //
    }
    else if {
        quant = quant + 1;
    //(sum the quantity of times a value has been greater than -1)//
    }
}
}
printf("The average value is:", suma/quant); ///(sun of all values > -1)/(sum of  quantity value was > -1)/
```

Find Maximum:

```
// Max

int variableP = a[0][0];
value = a[i][j];

int variableP = a[i][j]
for(i=0; i<21; i++){
    for(j=0; j<21; j++){
        if(variableP < newvalue){
            variableP = newvalue
        }
    }
}
printf("The max value of the 2D array is", %d);
```

Average and Maximum:

```
// max and average

int maxvg();
int max=INT_MIN, sum=0, count=0, avg;

for(i = 0; i < 21; i++){
    for(j =0; j < 21; j++){
        if(current > -1){
            sum = sum + current;
            count = count + 1
            if(current > max){
                max = current;
            }
        }

    }
}
avg = sum/count;
printf("Max is %d \n", max);
printf("Average is %d \n", avg);
```

So how right or wrong is this? what am i missing.
i mostly get:

```
[Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
[Warning] data definition has no type or storage class
[Error] initializer element is not constant
[Error] expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
```

Am i at least close to it?

Thanks in advance.

END OF EDIT

I created a 2D array with random numbers from 0 to 100 (and a couple of -1) values with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main ()
{

    int a[21][21], i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
            a[i][j] = GetRand (0, 100);
            a[7][15] = -1;
            a[10][6] = -1;
            a[13][5] = -1;
            a[15][17] = -1;
            a[17][17] = -1;
            a[19][6] = -1;
            printf ("%3d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}



// random seed
int GetRand (int min, int max);
int get ()
{
    int i, r;
    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        r = GetRand (0, 100);
        printf ("Your number is %d \n", r);
    }
    return (0);
}

int GetRand (int min, int max)
{
    static int Init = 0;
    int rc;

    if (Init == 0) {
        srand (time (NULL));
        Init = 1;
    }

    rc = (rand () % (max - min + 1) + min);

    return (rc);
}
```

This prints the array created. Now I want to calculate the maximum value of all  values inside the array and the total average of all values in the array, all while ignoring all -1 values, so only from 0 to 100. Since I'm a total beginner I'm having problems creating these functions. So here are my ideas.

```
//For the average
for(i=0; i<1; i++){
   for(j=0; j<21; j++){

  if (actualvalue > -1){
  //sum actualvalue + nextvalue (sum of all the values greater than -1)//
 }
 else if (actualvalue > -1){
 //(sum the quantity of times a value has been greater than -1)//
 }
  }
   }
    }
printf("The average value is", //(sum of all values>-1)/(sum of quantity value was >-1) //);
```

I'm representing the thing i don't know how to write in code in words so you get my idea.

Now for finding the maximum: what i think i should do is initialize the array and make a variable adopt the first value it finds that's > -1, then rewind and initialize again, if the actualvalue < newvalue then make variableP adopt the newvalue:

```
//max
int variableP = a[i][j]
for(i=0; i<21; i++){
for(j=0;j<21;j++){
  if(variableP < newvalue){
 variableP = newvalue
}
printf("The max value of the 2D array is", %d);
 }
```

I know it's evident i'm not sure what i'm writing here, but i think my idea of it is correct, i hope i'm explaining it well enough.

Comment: In both the "average" and the "max" code you need a line like `value=a[i][j];` to get a value from the array. In the "max" code the first line should be `int variableP = a[0][0];`

Comment: Declare `int GetRand(int min, int max);` before `main()` calls it.

Comment: Suspicious that "Average" code does `//For the average for(i=0; i<1; i++){` and not `for(i=0; i<21; i++) {`  (1 vs.21)

Comment: What are your trying got do with `value = a[i][j];`?  What does this code mean to you?

Comment: Would that be the actual value that is being read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both max and avg in one loop.

Declare three variables: max=-999999, sum=0, count=0.

Each time when current cell is not -1 increase sum by it's value and count by 1.

Each time check if current value is bigger than max, then set max to current value.

After the loop is done, avg = sum/count.

Comment: Note: `max=INT_MIN` is more idiomatic than `max=-999999`

Answer (score 1):

Sum is as you say.
Average requires you count number of >-1 values.
Max looks right lines.  Finish off your ideas and ask again if it doesn't work

Comment: it's not working but i think i'm close, is it that i wrote wrong the actions after the conditions in the if's statements?

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are doing all your arithmetic using integers, and integer division is integer.  Perhaps you have better to do a `double` result with:

```
/* you don't actually need to cast to double in both operators, as the
 * one not casted will be automagically casted to double to operate on.
 */
double average = (double) sum_of_samples / (double) number_of_samples;
```

You have to cast at least one of the operators, because if you don't you'll get the result as before (a `0` integer result) converted to `double` to assign to the variable.